TypeScript Error with PrometheusExporter in OpenTelemetry SDK: Type 'PrometheusExporter' is not assignable to type 'MetricReader'
I'm using OpenTelemetry in a TypeScript project, specifically @opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus to expose metrics at /metrics. I’ve paired it with MeterProvider from @opentelemetry/sdk-metrics:
import { PrometheusExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus';
import { MeterProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';

import { config } from '../config';

export const startPrometheusReceiver = () => {
    const exporter = new PrometheusExporter({
        port: config.port,
        endpoint: '/metrics',
    });
    const meterProviderProm = new MeterProvider({
        readers: [exporter], // The error is here under exporter.
        interval: 1000,
    });
    return meterProviderProm;
};

However, TypeScript is throwing a compatibility error between PrometheusExporter and MetricReader. The error I receive is:
Type 'PrometheusExporter' is not assignable to type 'MetricReader'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property '_shutdown'.

Despite this error, the code runs successfully, and the metrics are exposed on /metrics as expected. I suspect this might be related to a compatibility issue between the 0.x version of @opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus and the 1.x version of @opentelemetry/sdk-metrics:
"@opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus": "^0.53.0",
"@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics": "^1.27.0"

I attempted to directly cast PrometheusExporter as a MetricReader (e.g., exporter as MetricReader) to avoid the TypeScript error, but this didn’t resolve the underlying issue. Additionally, I explored using PeriodicExportingMetricReader, but it didn’t appear to solve the compatibility issue.
I expected PrometheusExporter to work with MeterProvider without any TypeScript errors, given that PrometheusExporter is supposed to extend MetricReader. I’m looking for either a workaround to resolve this TypeScript error or confirmation on compatibility issues between these OpenTelemetry packages.

"@opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus": "^0.54.0" seems to solve the issue.

"@opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus": "^0.54.0"

Seems to solve the issue.
